# Using $(this) in .js.erb file - Ruby on Rails AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails3 with jQuery and attempting to do simple ajax calls. I have a link that displays the current status (online/offline) of an application. When clicked it will update the status.

```
link_to app.status, { :controller => :apps, :action => :live_status, :id => app }, {:remote => true, :class => "#{app.status} status"}
```

live_status.js.erb:

```
$(this).fadeOut();
$(this).parent().html("<%= escape_javascript(status_link(@wowza_app)) %>");
$(this).fadeIn();
```

status_link will return the updated link_to

However $(this) isn't working how I envision. How can I update the clicked status with the new status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use a selector. When you have that code interpreted in the ajax response, jQuery doesn't know what "this" are you referring. Better use something like:

```
$('#my-special-div').fadeOut();
$('#my-special-div').parent().html("<%= escape_javascript(status_link(@wowza_app)) %>");
$('#my-special-div').fadeIn();
$('#my-special-div').hide(2000, function () {
    $(this).remove();  // here jQuery knows you are talking about 'my-special-div'
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You should give the element you want to update an ID (I added an element to the hash at the very end):

```
link_to app.status, { :controller => :apps, :action => :live_status, :id => app }, {:remote => true, :class => "#{app.status} status", :id => app.id}
```

Now, you can use that same identifier to select the right element with jQuery:

```
$("#<%= @wowza_app.id %>").fadeOut();
$("#<%= @wowza_app.id %>").parent().html("<%= escape_javascript(status_link(@wowza_app)) %>");
$("#<%= @wowza_app.id %>").fadeIn();
```

Of course, this assumes that `@wowza_app` has a method called `id` that returns the same ID of the link, but you can modify the variables as necessary to select the element with the right ID.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I was trying to avoid just adding in extra IDs, but I guess there really is no harm.