# How to use $(this) in a .js.erb file without using IDs (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a dynamically generated list of divs of class 'book'. The partial looks like this:

_book.html.erb:

```
<div class="book">
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_book_path(book), remote: true %>

    <div class="content">
        <%= link_to book.title, book.link %> 
    </div>

    <div class="editform" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

books_controller:

```
def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

This is what I want to do: I want to get the parent div of the link that called edit, and then change its children classes. Obviously $(this) isn't working.

Someone asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086782/using-this-in-js-erb-file-ruby-on-rails-ajax) 3 years ago and all responses say to use IDs. I really don't want to refer to specific elements by ID in edit.js.erb because they're dynamically generated (I could do it if I have to but I'm sure there's a nice way to do this).

books/edit.js.erb (not working)

```
var $bookdiv = $(this).parent();
$bookdiv.find('.editform').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'books/formBookFull', book: @book)%>");
$bookdiv.find('.editform').show();
$bookdiv.find('.content').hide();
```

Is there a good way to do this or a nice alternative? I've also tried making this an onclick function right in the partial as a temporary hack but even that's not working because jquery isn't working in the partial for some reason.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Put quotes around your selectors: .find('.editform') ...

Comment: everybody has errors like that ;)

Comment: Edited to fix that. But the issue is the $(this)--if I take out everything but the first line, the javascript is still broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use your record id, HTML5 `data` attributes are made exactly for this kind of scenario

_book.html.erb:

```
<div class="book" data-id="<%= book.id %>">
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_book_path(book), remote: true %>

    <div class="content">
        <%= link_to book.title, book.link %> 
    </div>

    <div class="editform" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

edit.js.erb

```
var $bookdiv = $('div.book[data-id="<%= @book.id %>"]');
$bookdiv.find('.editform').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'books/formBookFull', book: @book)%>");
$bookdiv.find('.editform').show();
$bookdiv.find('.content').hide();
```

Comment: That's wonderful! I need to go read about HTML5 data attributes now.

Comment: Yep you can achieve many things with this, `data` in HTML are convenient for passing application related information, and `data` on the javascript side are more complex and can store javascript object (and there are some gotcha when updating a `data` value in javascript). But in your case it's pretty simple